# Why can't I cast a `u32` to `char`?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to learn Rust and I got caught up thinking about how `char`s are 4 bytes wide. I can cast a `char` to a `u32` and it works out (they are both 4 bytes wide), however, when I cast from a `u32` to a `char`, Rust complains:

```
fn main() {
    let pizza_hex: u32 = 0x1f355;
    let pizza: char = ''; // (pizza char: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f355/index.htm)

    // pizza as hex = 1f355
    println!("pizza as hex = {:x}", pizza as u32);

    // size of pizza = 4
    println!("size of pizza = {}", std::mem::size_of_val(&pizza));

    // This doesn't work super well
    println!("{} == {}", pizza_hex as char, pizza);
}
```

```
error[E0604]: only `u8` can be cast as `char`, not `u32`
  --> src/main.rs:12:26
   |
12 |     println!("{} == {}", pizza_hex as char, pizza);
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Rust have an equivalent to Python's unichr() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531265/does-rust-have-an-equivalent-to-pythons-unichr-function)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Every `char` is a valid `u32` value, but *not* every `u32` value is a valid `char`.

The property of `char`s holding valid Unicode codepoints [factors into memory safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html):

> ### Behavior considered undefined
>
> - Invalid values in primitive types, even in private fields and locals:
>
>   - A value in a `char` which is a surrogate or above `char::MAX`.

To convert a `u32` to a `char` at runtime, try this:

```
if let Some(pizza_from_hex) = std::char::from_u32(pizza_hex) {
    println!("{} == {}", pizza_from_hex, pizza);
}
```

If you just don't want creepy Unicode glyphs in your character literals, you can use Unicode escape sequences:

```
let pizza_from_hex = '\u{01f355}';

println!("{} == {}", pizza_from_hex, pizza);
```

Comment: So in the case when I have a valid unicode character (`0x1f355`) as an `u32`, I still cannot convert it? (Highly contrived example warning:) If I wanted to print out a non-visible character (such as a zero width space), I would have to deal the internals of string handling in an `unsafe` block?

Comment: Sorry, just amended my answer. No need for `unsafe` here, the stdlib wraps the `unsafe` logic.

Comment: I think in cases where one must print some known character, a escape sequence/documentation is probably best for weird glyphs.

Comment: I think `std::mem::transmute` can also be used in this situation? And wondering if there is a way to cast without involving stdlib.

Comment: Is there a way to "unwrap_or" with the closest valid value?