# Does Rust have an equivalent to Python's unichr() function?

Tags: rust

Python has the [`unichr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr) (or `chr()` in Python 3) function that takes an integer and returns a character with the Unicode code point of that number. Does Rust have an equivalent function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, though it is a built-in operator `as`:

```
let c: char = 97 as char;
println!("{}", c);   // prints "a"
```

Note that `as` operator works only for `u8` numbers, something else will cause a compilation error:

```
let c: char = 97u32 as char;  // error: only `u8` can be cast as `char`, not `u32`
```

If you need a string (to fully emulate the Python function), use `to_string()`:

```
let s: String = (97 as char).to_string();
```

There is also the [`char::from_u32`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/char/fn.from_u32.html) function:

```
use std::char;
let c: Option<char> = char::from_u32(97);
```

It returns an `Option<char>` because not every number is a valid Unicode code point - the only valid numbers are 0x0000 to 0xD7FF and from 0xE000 to 0x10FFFF. This function is applicable to a larger set of values than `as char` and can convert numbers larger than one byte, providing you access to the whole range of Unicode code points.

I've compiled a [set of examples on the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=cddf28e75663bc452462a8d632eec09b&version=stable).

Comment: Interesting enough `let c4 = 0xd801 as char; println!("{:?}", c4);` works with a warning.

Comment: It works incorrectly - it interprets `0xd801` as a `u8`, wrapping the value around to `1u8` and converting that to `char`. [Here](http://is.gd/mI5wme) is a demonstration.

Comment: Right, I only meant that it emits a warning and returns a value.