# Python's chr() and ord() in Rust

Tags: rust, chr, ord

In Python you can convert an integer into a character and a character into an integer with [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) and [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr):

```python
>>>a = "a"
>>>b = ord(a) + 1
>>>b = chr(b)
```

I am looking for a way to do the same thing in Rust, but I have found nothing similar yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Rust have an equivalent to Python's unichr() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531265/does-rust-have-an-equivalent-to-pythons-unichr-function)

Comment: @user3840170 Hmm... The OP also wants the opposite, which is as simple as `as u32`, but I don't see it mentioned on the linked question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the available [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) and [`TryInto`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryInto.html) implementations:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a: char = 'a';
    let mut b: u32 = a.into(); // char implements Into<u32>
    b += 1;
    a = b.try_into().unwrap(); // We have to use TryInto trait here because not every valid u32 is a valid unicode scalar value
    println!("{}", a);
}
```

Comment: it's exactly what I was lookin for.
Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

`ord` can be done using the [`as` keyword](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.as.html):

```rust
let c = 'c';
assert_eq!(99, c as u32);
```

While `chr` using the [`char::from_u32()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.from_u32) function:

```rust
let c = char::from_u32(0x2728);
assert_eq!(Some('✨'), c);
```

Note that `char::from_u32()` returns an `Option<char>` in case the number isn't a valid codepoint. There's also [`char::from_u32_unchecked()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.from_u32_unchecked).